# Include images in haproxy errorfile

Tags: haproxy

Is there a proper way to add an image to a page being served by errorfile in haproxy. As it stands, adding an image directly in the page will result in a broken image. I have looked into using errorloc to redirect to an error page offsite, but that seemed liked overkill. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *"adding an image directly in the page will result in a broken image."*  Why do you say this?  What do you mean "directly in" the page? How big is the image?

Comment: I should include I'm using errorlog 503, so I'm assuming the link to the image is being rewritten, for example, if I try to access the link directly via example.com/image.jpg, it redirects to the 503 error page.

Comment: Well, right, on a 503 the back-end is down so the image isn't going to be accessible. :)  If the image is small, you could embed it in the error page as base64.  How large is the image?  Let me know and I'll describe that, and a couple of alternatives in an answer.

Comment: The image is 28KB. Thanks.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Can you make it smaller? Compression, quality reduction?  Specifically, can you get it down to about `((16384 - current_size_of_errorfile) * 3 / 4)`?

Comment: I reduced it to 8KB. Can't go any further without losing a fair bit of quality.